# ASP.net MVC View Creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I heard that ASP.net MVC does not maintain View State.So,here is my question

I have an MVC -View which has forward and backward html button.When i click forward and again 
click backward ,how can i maintain html control state then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to handle state in ASP.NET MVC:

1. Request parameters
2. Hidden fields
3. Session

There's also a [nice helper](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/03/06/persisting-model-state-in-asp-net-mvc-using-html-serialize.aspx) in ASP.NET Futures that allow you to serialize/deserialize models using view state.